# Problems with glReadPixels in android

Tags: android, picking, glreadpixels

I am trying to implement an opengl picking system I read about and have hit an issue with glReadPixels. Basically, every node in the scene gets a unique color and when a new touch happens, it renders the scene with nothing but the nodes painted with their unique color ids. I am trying to check the input coordinate with a list of stored color ids.

I can not get glReadPixels to work right. It always returns 0 0 0 for pixel values. i would really appreciate any help with getting the correct pixel values from it. thanks

here is the relevant code

```
private void handleEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    if (actionCode == 0) {
        // Paint with colorID color
        mSettings.picking(true);
        dumpEvent(event);
        final GL10 gl = mSettings.getGL();

        ByteBuffer PixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
        PixelBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        gl. glPixelStorei(gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        gl.glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, PixelBuffer);
        byte b[] = new byte[4];
        PixelBuffer.get(b);
        String key = "" + b[0] + b[1] + b[2];       
        // Check for selection
        mRenderer.processSelection(event, new SGColorI(pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]));

        log.pl("GL on touchdown", key);
    } else if (actionCode == 2) {
        mSettings.picking(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Even Depth buffer also couldn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

`allocateDirect` "just doesn't work" in this case. Use `allocate`.

It seemed very strange to me, but allocate vs `allocateDirect` was the only difference I came to.

Also [this post in google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/997f21e9c9d33006/01b52fc96af6bc53) helped me a lot.

btw, this discovery was made on emulator (several different versions), not the real device.

Answer (score 0):

The use of glReadPixels for the classical pick problem is overkilled. Remember that glReadPixels is a blocking function, while openGL works mainly in an asynchronous way. Using glReadPixels means that all the commands in the driver queue have to be processed and this could be a huge waste of time.